Issues using solve_ivp for a multidimensional problem
Im trying to model a steel rod being heated from below on a plate. To model this it is broken down into axial and radial segments. I want to find the temperature change of these segments over time with them plotted on a series of graphs as a heatmap. I am trying to loop through the radial segments within each vertical segment before moving onto the next vertical segment but it seems to be solving the whole matrix at once. This is obviously messing up plotting and making it difficult for me to work that out as the solutions produced by solve_ivp seem to be disconnected from time. Any help would be appreciated.
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
import numpy as np 
from scipy.integrate import solve_ivp

Parameters
n = 5 # number of segments the rod is divided into radially m = 3   # number of segments the rod is divided into axially D = 0.1  # rod diameter (m) Cp = 500  # specific heat capacity of rod (J/kg K) rho = 8000  # density of rod (kg/m3) k = 20  # thermal conductivity of rod (W/mK) L = 0.5  # length of the rod (m) r = (D/2)/m # distance between the centre of each segment in j direction, change in radius(m) z = L / n  # distance between the centre of each segment in i direction, length of a segment (m) U = 18  # overall heat transfer coefficient from the surface (W/m2K) U_top = 18  # overall heat transfer coefficient at the top of the rod (W/m2K) T_amb = 290  # ambient temperature (K) T_plate = 500  # temperature of the plate (K) T_ref = 273  # reference temperature equivalent to 0 deg C (K)
def Energy_eqns(t, y):

y = y.reshape((m, n))  # Reshape the 1D temperature array to 2D
dTdt_array = np.zeros((m, n))  # temperature array (n segments x m radial segments)

for i in range(m):
    for j in range(n):
        # Area of the top or bottom face of the segment (m2)
        A = np.pi * (((j + 1) * r) ** 2 - (j * r) ** 2)
        # Area of the outermost face of the segment in the radial direction (m2)
        S = 2 * np.pi * (j + 1) * r * z

        # Heat flux entering the segment (axial direction)
        if i == 0:
            Qi_1 = (k * A * (T_plate - y[i, j])) / (z / 2)
        else:
            Qi_1 = (k * A * (y[i - 1, j] - y[i, j])) / z

        # Heat flux exiting the segment through the top face (axial direction)
        if i < m - 1:
            Qi = k * A * (y[i, j] - y[i + 1, j]) / z
        else:
            Qi = U_top * A * (y[i, j] - T_amb)

        # Heat flux entering radial segment
        if j > 0:
            Qrj_1 = k * S * (y[i, j - 1] - y[i, j]) / r
        else:
            Qrj_1 = 0

        # Heat flux exiting radial segment
        if j < n - 1:
            Qrj = k * S * (y[i, j] - y[i, j + 1]) / r
        else:
            Qrj = U * S * (y[i, j] - T_amb)  # Heat flux leaving the segment through the exposed sides (axial direction)

        # Change in energy
        dEi_dt = Qi_1 + Qrj_1 - Qi - Qrj

        dTdt_array[i, j] = dEi_dt

return dTdt_array.flatten()  # Return flattened array for solve_ivp

Initial temperatures for each segment (K)
initial_temperatures = np.ones((m, n)) * T_amb  # Assuming all segments initially at ambient temperature
Time span to integrate over (seconds)
t_span = (0, 100)  # Integrate for 100 seconds
Solve the system of differential equations
sol = solve_ivp(Energy_eqns, t_span, initial_temperatures.flatten(), method='LSODA', t_eval=np.linspace(0, 10, 100)) t = sol.t
print(t)
print(sol.y.reshape((len(t), n, m)))
Extract the temperatures over time
t = sol.t  # Time points
temperatures = sol.y.reshape((len(t), n, m))  # Reshape to (time, axial segments, radial segments) print(temperatures)
Define time intervals for plotting
plot_intervals = t
for time_interval in plot_intervals: # Find the index of the nearest time step to the desired time interval index = np.abs(t - time_interval).argmin()

# Create a new figure for each time interval
fig, ax = plt.subplots()

# Define a fixed temperature range for the color scale
vmin = np.min(temperatures)   # Minimum temperature across all time steps
vmax = np.max(temperatures) +20 # Maximum temperature across all time steps

# Plot the adjusted temperature profile at the selected time step as a heatmap
im = ax.imshow(temperatures[index].T, cmap='hot', aspect='auto', origin='lower', vmin=vmin, vmax=vmax)


# Add labels and title
ax.set_xlabel('Axial Segment')
ax.set_ylabel('Radial Segment')
ax.set_title(f'Temperature Profile at Time = {time_interval} s')

# Add colorbar to the plot
plt.colorbar(im, ax=ax, label='Temperature (K)')

# Show the plot for the current time interval
plt.show()


Please fix the formatting of your code.

Can you fix the indentation in your code?
